A function in my code is not working properly
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>   
#define I 27
#define DosyaAdi "test.txt"

struct  müşteri
{
    char iban[I];
    long long tc;
    int bakiye;
};

int ibankontrol(char iban[])
{
    if(!isalpha(iban[0]) || !isalpha(iban[1]))
        return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (iban[i]<48 || iban[i]>57)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int tckontrol(long long tc)
{
    int a=0,bas;
    long long i=1;
    while (a<11)
    {
        bas=(tc/i)%10;
        if (bas<0 || bas>9)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
        i*=10;
        a++;
    }
    if (tc / i > 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int kaydet(struct müşteri m)
{
    FILE *dosya;
    dosya=fopen(DosyaAdi,"a");
    if (dosya==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nKayıt başarısız\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    fprintf(dosya,"%lld %d %s\n",m.tc,m.bakiye,m.iban);

    fclose(dosya);
    return 1;
}

int havale(char kaynak[],char hedef[],int miktar)
{
    struct müşteri müşteriler[100];
    int i=0,y=0,z=0;
    char string[100];
    FILE *dosya;
    dosya=fopen(DosyaAdi,"r");
    while (1)
    {
        if ((fgets(string,100,dosya))==NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        sscanf(string,"%lld %d %s",&müşteriler[i].tc,&müşteriler[i].bakiye,müşteriler[i].iban);
        i++;
    }   

    for(z=0;z<i;z++)
    {
        printf("\nGuncel bilgiler:\n");
        printf("%d: %s  %lld  %d\n",z+1,müşteriler[z].iban,müşteriler[z].tc,müşteriler[z].bakiye);
    }

    fclose(dosya);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(kaynak,müşteriler[j].iban) == 0)
        {
            müşteriler[j].bakiye -= miktar;
            y++;
        }
        if (strcmp(hedef,müşteriler[j].iban) == 0)
        {
            müşteriler[j].bakiye += miktar;
            y++;
        }
    }

    if (y != 2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    dosya = fopen(DosyaAdi, "w");
    if (dosya == NULL)
    {
        printf("Dosya açılamadı.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    for (int s = 0; s < i; s++)
    {
        fprintf(dosya, "%lld %d %s", müşteriler[s].tc, müşteriler[s].bakiye, müşteriler[s].iban);
        if (s!=i-1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        
    }
    fclose(dosya);
    
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    int seçim;
    int dönüş=0,kontrol=0;
    char kaynak[27],hedef[27];
    int miktar=0;
    struct müşteri m;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Menü:\n");
        printf("1:Kayıt\n");
        printf("2:Havale\n");
        printf("3:Çıkış\n");
        printf("Seçiminiz: ");
        scanf("%d",&seçim);

        switch (seçim)
        {
        case 1:
       
            while (1)
            {
                printf("İban giriniz: ");
                scanf("%s",m.iban);
                fflush(stdin);
                dönüş=ibankontrol(m.iban);
                if (dönüş==0)
                {
                    printf("İban yanlış");
                }
                else if (dönüş==1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (1)
            {
                printf("TC giriniz");
                scanf("%lld",&m.tc);
                dönüş=tckontrol(m.tc);
                if (dönüş==0)
                {
                    printf("TC yanlış");
                }
                else if (dönüş==1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            printf("Bakiye giriniz");
            scanf("%d",&m.bakiye);

            kontrol=kaydet(m);
            if (kontrol==0)
            {
                printf("Kayıt başarısız");
            }
            else if (kontrol==1)
            {
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Kaynak iban: ");
            scanf("%s",kaynak);
             
            fflush(stdin);
            
            printf("Hedef iban: ");
            scanf("%s",hedef);
   
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("Gönderilicek miktar: ");
            scanf("%d",&miktar);

            int a=havale(kaynak,hedef,miktar);
            if (a==0)
            {
                printf("Havale başarısız\n");
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(2);
            break;
        default:
            printf("geçersiz işlem");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

In my code, as information is entered, I process it into the file, and then, when making the transfer, I delete the file and write it back to the file after the transaction. While the registration process is performed properly in my code, the transfer transaction does not occur properly. I think it is a whitespace character, but what do you think?

What is the exact input you are providing? What is your expected output? What is the actual output?

You should read Using fflush(stdin)

Don't use code like if (iban[i]<48 || iban[i]>57). Use if (!isdigit(iban[i]))

Printf a \n for the last line too, and scanf with a newline. Also you do not check that tc could be negative.

Error messages belong on stderr and should include a reason: if (dosya == NULL) { perror(DosyaAdi); ...}

@JoopEggen: You said "and scanf with a newline".  If by that you meant "end the scanf() format with a newline", then that's extremely bad advice.  See What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?  See also Using fflush(stdin)? and scanf() leaves the newline in the buffer?

@JonathanLeffler is of course right; I meant to consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240807/984823 . While commenting sscanf(data, "%ms", &buffer) might be a solution to buffer overflow. (string allocating scanf, of course evil input could cause very longs strings).

Printf a \n for the last line too, and scanf with a newline. Also you do not check that tc could be negative.
And IBAN does not reserve room for a terminating '\0', neither is there a check up on termination, like strlen. So printf and scanf will err.

OH,Thanks for the sscnf and printf tip.I will do it again with other functions

When you write to the file, you have no delimiter after the iban field. So when you try to read from the file, the next item's tc will be read as part of iban, and you'll get out of sync.
Write each item to a different line. The newline will terminate reading iban.
fprintf(dosya, "%lld %d %s\n", müşteriler[s].tc, müşteriler[s].bakiye, müşteriler[s].iban);


Is there a way to do it in threes, one under the other, or is it the exact way you say?

You can use "%lld\n%d\n%s\n" to write each value on its own line. When scanning, any whitespace acts as a delimiter.
